# Storing Joda LocalDateTime and LocalDate in Hibernate 5.1 and mapping globally

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jodatime

I need to store `LocalDate` into `DATE` and `LocalDateTime` into `DATETIME/TIMESTAMP`. I am using Hibernate 5.

I have read that I should use `@Type` annotation on every column, and it works. But I would like to try to map all columns that happen to be `LocalDateTime` to be `TIMESTAMP` at once.

I have tried in my `package-info.java`

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs({
        @org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef(defaultForType = org.joda.time.LocalDateTime.class, typeClass = org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentLocalDateTime.class, name = "LocalDateTime"),
        @org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef(defaultForType = org.joda.time.LocalDate.class, typeClass = org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentLocalDate.class, name = "LocalDate"), //
})
```

No result.

Any idea?